# linear-gradient with background image displays differently on ios mobile

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, background-image, linear-gradients

I'm trying to achieve exactly this, using chrome on mobile ios device.
It looks perfect on desktop, just not on mobile.
CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("data:image/png;base64,my image b64");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("data:image/png;base64,my image b64");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 64px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    color: white;
}
```

The image is 16x16px. Here's what it looks like in browser first:
[image]

Here's what it looks like on chrome ios mobile:
[image]

The upscaling doesn't seem to be working, but also the gradient.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: try min-height:100% to html

Comment: @TemaniAfif No dice :(

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding an absolute positioned div with 100% width and height with z-index -1000 and applied the linear gradient to that. Looks great on firefox, chrome and their mobile counterparts.

For the upscaling I used image-rendering: crisp-edges and pixelated and the -webkit variants for all around support.

Hope that's useful for someone :)